# Updating all lists in Xamarin form SQLite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am using the listview of the same SQLite Table and I am facing a problem as I add new items or update the previous one it updates the values on the current page but need to reopen the app to update the list on Page B. Do you have any solution?[Before Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkb0X.jpg)
[Updated Value here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3HTc.jpg)
[Did'nt update here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPyjh.jpg)
so can you help me by giving me a link or video?

Comment: You need to post the relevant code if you expect us to help you.

Comment: Hi! Which is your ItemSource for the ListView? Are you using Binding, NotiftyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: please note that posting code or errors as images is not acceptable on SO.  Please read [ask] for more info on the posting guidelines

Answer (score 0):

For adding and deleting items from list and make changes instantly, you need to use `ObservableCollection` in `System.Collections.ObjectModel`. There's no difference whether using SQLite or not; it's about list.

Here is an example:

```
public partial class Page : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Client> _client;
    public SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
    
    public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        //initialize database
        await connection.CreateTableAsync<CLient>();
        var listofclient = await connection.Table<Client>().ToListAsync();

        //initialize observablecollection 
        _client = new ObservableCollection<Client>(listofclients);

        //using the list of client as source of listview
        clientListveiw.ItemsSource = _client;
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
    
    //add button
    private async void onadd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new Client { Name = "jhon"};
        await connection.InsertAsync(patient);
        _client.Add(patient);
    }
}
```

And about the update, you should use `INotifyPropertyChange` interface; its a long story, but you can google it for further information.